# Merging SO Careers and SO [Jobs] accounts

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, accounts

Why just not to discontinue SO Careers account in favor of consolidated SO account?
I think it will be extremely convenient for everybody. Trudging through the dozens of accounts we used today, it will be wise to eliminate at least this one.

Comment: Because SO Careers will be for the employer side.  As to why we don't merge it, its to avoid issues like this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196065/138999

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the site purely as a candidate, you will have no need for any other account than your Stack Overflow account.  This account will encompass all of Q&A and Jobs (CV, search preferences, communication with employers etc...)

You will need to create another employer account at careers.stackoverflow.com if you wish to act as an employer to post jobs or search our database of CV's.

Comment: And if I delete my SO Careers account will my CV remain in my main SO profile?