# Jobs vs Careers vs Developer Story vs Talent

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story, stack-overflow-talent

This current question is closely connected to my previous questions, so they should be recalled here.
From the very beginning I [haven't understand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313173/merging-so-careers-and-so-jobs-accounts) the use of distinct Careers account and integrated Jobs within SO account. OK, you did it and let it be.
 However, misconceptions and disrepancies [were not long in coming](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336461/my-cv-is-completely-lost-after-developer-story-release).
In the latter question I was answered:

> Careers was not a site used exclusively by employers, users were able to search for and apply for jobs with the CV on the site

and that brought more confusion than ever.

I thoroughly read [introduction of Jobs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow), and doubled introduction ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313960/introducing-the-developer-story/314040#314040), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/the-developer-story-part-2-we-didnt-explain-that-very-well/314697#314697)) of Developer Story, but have **still no clear idea** of the difference between them. The evolution of job search on SO as I see it:

Careers >> Jobs on SO >> Developer Story

Each historical stage was *probably* better than previous one, but the question(s) I very interested in lays in the technical side:

1. Is account on certain resource linked to another resources and in what way? How do they interconnected?
2. Does deleting/changing account on one resource affect all other resources?
3. Are they bound to StackExchange account and could they be changed separately?
4. Should I give up some of them if I am not employer or they are both-sided (employee + employer)?

Now I am facing four different but overlapping services:
[SO Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) | [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) | [Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current) | [Talent](http://talent.stackoverflow.com)

Can anybody answer above questions referring to these services?

Comment: I don't think Developers Story or Talents overlap with any of the others. Talents appears to be a service for helping employers learn *how* to attract and retain quality employees, not an actual hiring service. Developer Story is an alternate way to display your CV/resume.

Comment: so Jobs and Developer Story are two views of the single entity? Of my CV?

Comment: I'm not sure about Jobs & Careers. I thought Jobs was replacing Careers and didn't realize Careers was still available. Hopefully someone who's used some of these will provide some insight.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Now I am facing four different but overlapping services:
>
> SO Jobs | Careers | Developer Story | Talent

Careers is gone. It's been replaced by [Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) (the candidate-facing side, integrated into SO) and [Talent](http://talent.stackoverflow.com) (the employer-facing side; separate site).

Developer Story is a *feature* of Jobs and set to replace the traditional CV, although there's a traditional view for those who prefer it.

> Is account on certain resource linked to another resources and in what
>   way? How do they interconnected? Does deleting/changing account on one
>   resource affect all other resources? Are they bound to StackExchange
>   account and could they be changed separately? Should I give up some of
>   them if I am not employer or they are both-sided (employee +
>   employer)?

[Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) is part of Stack Overflow. Everything jobs-related, in particular your developer story, is linked to your Stack Overflow account.

[Talent](http://talent.stackoverflow.com) is a separate site which uses a separate account.

If you're using both (as a candidate and as an employer, respectively), you can manage both accounts individually. For example, changing your Talent password does not automatically change your Stack Overflow password.

Comment: Ok, now it's somehow clear for me.

Comment: Only "somehow"? :) Anything still not clear?

Comment: Previous status-quo, when Careers was linked to Jobs, brought a bit of confusion.

Comment: Rather clear, I'd say)